# Optaplanner - Medium score not improving

Tags: optaplanner

The problem I am trying to solve is a 'cloud-balancing' like problem, and I chose to use Hard/Medium/Soft score structure. Each planning value has a 'capacity' of how many planning entities can be assigned, and my score structure looks like:

Hard - assignments cannot exceed the capacity of a planning value (negative)

Medium - assign a penalty (negative score) when the assignment of a planning value is under its capacity

Soft - add the score gained by matching a pair (the input data has a score table of all the possible pairs; positive score)

It works normally fine until I recently find out when there is a 'big' planning value (i.e. much larger capacity), some planning values are under-assigned. In terms of scores, the planner started by improving the medium scores quickly but once it reached a stage, the medium score stopped improving but only the soft score was improving.

I've tried moving this medium constraint to hard constraint, or by increasing the weight of the penalty, but none is working.

My understanding is as long as there is a 'big' planning value, it got hit more frequently than other planning values during move selection. However, I still don't see why when there is clearly a way to improve the medium score (at the end there are still plenty of planning entities available to be assigned to those under-assigned planning values), but the planner didn't do that but only focused on improving the soft scores...

I've kept the session running for hours but it doesn't help. My feeling is this may be a 'score trap' - perhaps I should somehow 'normalize' each planning value when writing that medium constraint?

Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Thanks folks.

Comment: Do you use pillarChangeMoveSelector and pillarSwapMoveSelector?

Comment: No, but I do have changeMoveSelector and swapMoveSelector implemented. The changeMoveSelector implemented a valueSelector and an entitySelector.

Comment: Can you try adding those other 2 selectors so you have 4 selectors? Those tend to help to escape local optima.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, thanks for your suggestion. I have tried adding those two selectors on top of existing selectors, but it doesn't solve the problem but the session running slower.

Comment: Without a deep code review it's hard to say what the problem is. Do setup the benchmarker if you haven't already - especially the best score over time graph is useful in such situations. See my "bottleneck" blog. It might be stuck in a local optima, which could be due to score trap or due to a need for custom course-grained moves. Or it could be just too slow (ACC < 1k).

Comment: Can see from benchmarking report that the medium score improved until a stage and then went flat while the soft score continued increasing. I am thinking about create two methods of 'setAvailability' and 'getAvailability' in the planning variable class, so that in the move selector I can make the under-assigned planning values at the top of the list? But I am not sure how to call the set method during planning to update the availability info of each planning variable (I am using DRL rules).

Comment: By the way, implementing custom move/factory classes in my case might not be a good idea. I've done that before but as the 'moveListFactory' scales badly in memory footprint and the problems I am trying to solve are usually very big, it easily got 'out of memory' error or huge performance loss.

Comment: OK, I added the update method in the DRL rule:
rule "UpdateComputerAvailability"
 when
  $computer: Computer( $capacity : capacity )
  ArrayList( $size : size )
                      from collect( Process( assignedComputer == $computer ))
 then
  $computer.setAvailbility( $capacity - $size );
end

Also I re-write the ComputerStrengthComparator as:
public int compare(Sales a, Sales b) {
   return new CompareToBuilder()
    .append(b.getAvailability(), a.getAvailability())
}

This class is used in valueSelector with sorterOrder as ASCENDING.

It's getting better but not 100%.